# Show WooCommerce cart count outside of Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, session-storage

I have a full website that I've built already. I have now installed Wordpress in a subdirectory (/shop) and I'm using WooCommerce to power the sale of products.

In the top menu bar while in the shop page I have a cart icon showing the number of products in the cart.

I would like that when the user clicks back into the non-Wordpress pages of the site to continue showing the number of items in the cart. Can someone point me in the right direction? I have tried to include the main class-woocommerce.php class but it's not working.

Here's what I have been using to test in my index.php file:

```
include 'shop/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-woocommerce.php';
global $woocommerce;
var_dump($woocommerce->cart);
```

---

**EDIT:**

I have now included wp-load.php instead of the class-woocommerce.php and when I dump the WooCommerce cart I can see it but it's completely empty, ie has 0 items even though I had items placed in the cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

This could be done also setting a custom cookie or better using javascript session storage this way:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_cart_item_count_script');
function custom_cart_item_count_script(){
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        $cart_count = 0;
    else
        $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    if(isset($cart_count)){
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($){
                var cartCount = <?php echo $cart_count; ?>,
                    csName = 'CARTCOUNT',
                    csStorage = sessionStorage.getItem(csName);

                if(csStorage == null || csStorage == 'undefined'){
                    sessionStorage.setItem(csName, cartCount);
                    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem(csName));
                }
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works.

---

**On your non Wordpress pages:**

You will need to get this browser session storage value. so you will add something like the following in your non Wordpress pages:

```
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            var caName = 'CARTCOUNT',
                caStorage = sessionStorage.getItem(caName);

            if(caStorage == null || caStorage == 'undefined')
                $('span.cart-count').html('0');
            else
                $('span.cart-count').html(caStorage);

            console.log('css-read: '+caStorage);
        });
    </script>
    <p>Cart count: <span class="cart-count"></span></p>
<?php
```

Tested and works:

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. That worked! For anyone else searching for the same, I also had to add:

define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');

before: require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php'); in the config.php file to make the cookie accessible in the parent directory.

I'm still having an issue though. It seems the cookie only stores the number of individual items, not multiples of the same item. If 4 of the same item in cart for example it still only says 1 in the cookie. Any idea how I can get the total number of all items? Thanks

Comment: @Sio I am glad for you… I think that can be done also with cookies, but it's more capricious. may be you can remove those old unnecessary comments before, please. Thanks